# Can the transform data from Power BI, change the Excel Worksheet data directly as well?

Tags: excel, powerbi, reporting

I imported data from an Excel Workbook and sheet to use with Power BI for reporting. The data however needed to be altered from format changes and deleting of empty rows and invalid input format corrected. I want the excel sheet afterwards to look the same as the formatted sheet in Power BI? Is this possible?

I tried to find a "live" connection between the two but once selecting the local Excel Workbook file the changes do not cross over.

Comment: No, not from Power BI.